# MongoDB Aggregation With $lookup for field inside an array

Tags: mongodb

Ive been trying to make a MongoDB query with aggregation to produce a data in a structure I like. So i have to collections namely `People` and `Calendar`

```
People

   _id : ObjectId,
   name: string,
   age: number,
   occupation: string
   address
```

```
Calendar
    _id: ObjectId,
    months: [
       {
          month: Date,
          users: [
                   {
                     PersonId: ObjectId(Reference from People._id)
                     ...some other details
                   },
                   {
                     PersonId: ObjectId(Reference from People._id)
                     ...some other details
                   },
                   {
                     PersonId: ObjectId(Reference from People._id)
                     ...some other details
                   },
          ]
       },
       {
         month: Date,
         users: [same as above]
       },
       {
         month: Date,
         users: [same as above]  
       },
    ]
```

So, what I would like the final data to look is like below.
Final Result

```
Calendar
    _id: ObjectId,
    months: [
       {
          month: Date,
          users: [
                   {
                     PersonId: ObjectId(Reference from People._id)
                     Person : data from Person Collection
                     ...some other details
                   },
                   {
                     PersonId: ObjectId(Reference from People._id)
                     Person : data from Person Collection
                     ...some other details
                   },
                   {
                     PersonId: ObjectId(Reference from People._id)
                     Person : data from Person Collection
                     ...some other details
                   },
          ]
       },
       {
         month: Date,
         users: [same as above]
       },
       {
         month: Date,
         users: [same as above]  
       },
    ]
```

I have been trying with below code but could not get it right.

```
.aggregate([
        {$unwind: "$months"},
        {$unwind: "$months.users"},
        
        {
          $lookup:
         {
            from: "Person",
            localField:  "months.users.PersonId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "PersonList"
          }
        },
        {$unwind: "$PersonList"},
        { 
          $group: 
          {
            "_id": "$_id",           
                                    
          } 
      
        }
      ])
```

How do I achieve this?
Is this something do-able?

Comment: is `months.month` unique?

Comment: Yes, `months.month` is unique. I mean, the value for `months.month` wont have duplicates. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can do something like this,

```
db.calender.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$months"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$months.users"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "people",
      localField: "months.users.personId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "months.users.people"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        _id: "$_id",
        months: "$months.month"
      },
      users: {
        $addToSet: "$months.users"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      months: {
        $push: {
          month: "$_id.months",
          users: "$users"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You need to add the details to nested array, So we use `unwind` two times, when we re-group it, we need to use two `groups`. The months array is uniquely identify by a unique field. (As you said `months.month` is unique, if it is not unique, give another filed `_id` which should be unique)

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5DVTEtIaH1i)

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. You are a life-saver